# DJango giving me an error when I use user.isAuthenticated

Tags: python, django

I am working on getting my Clubs website back up and running after our previous coder left. He left nothing behind so now when I run it, Django gives me the error:

`File "/home/serverad/django14_project/my_django15_project/tsa/events/views.py", line 112, in custom500
    return render_template('errors/500.mako', request, parent='../base.mako' if request.user.is_authenticated() else '../layout.mako')
    AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'`

I have no idea what's wrong seeing as though our last programmer left no notes behind.

Comment: did you upgrade Django? go to setting and tell me if is `MIDDLEWARE` or `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: @MauricioCortazar it is MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: change it to `MIDDLEWARE`

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I did it gave me the same error

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @MauricioCortazar Django it is 1.5.12

Comment: leave `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` it's for version under 1.11

Comment: @MauricioCortazar yeah it still gives me the error regardless

Comment: you should upgrade your Django version isn't supported anymore

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I did now it is giving the error “importerror: cannot import name execute manager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157414/discussion-between-mauricio-cortazar-and-ethan-baxter).

Answer (score 0):

i notice your a write a `custom500` function,when service return 500,the request object will not has user attr,change your code to:

```
if hasattr(request, 'user'):
    return render_template('errors/500.mako', request, parent='../base.mako' if request.user.is_authenticated() else '../layout.mako')
else:
    return render_template('errors/500.mako', request, '../layout.mako')
```

Comment: Currently the problem arose from the manage.py because of the wrong version and now it needs to be fixed.